# Wsdl array response:

Tags: wsdl

i want to split my response, I got my response as array. Could Anyone pls help me.

This is my output:

[image]

This is a code i written in developer console.

```
wwwXigniteComServices.XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap testCls = new wwwXigniteComServices.XigniteGlobalCurrenciesSoap();

wwwXigniteComServices.Header h = new wwwXigniteComServices.Header();

h.Username='*****';

h.Password='*****';

h.Tracer='****';

testCls.Header = h;

wwwXigniteComServices.Currencies ListCurrenciesResult = testCls.ListCurrencies();

System.debug(ListCurrenciesResult);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that **wwwXigniteComServices.Currencies** is some kind of class with properties, that store all the required information. Just check what's inside

Comment: Yes, it stored all needed info. Like, Countries, Countries_type_info,Digital, Digital_type_info, Message, Message_type_info, Name_type_info, Plural, Plural_type_info,Symbol=ADP,Symbol_type_info. \

Comment: But i don't need this response as array.

Comment: <Currency>
                  <Symbol>ADP</Symbol>
                  <Name>Andorran peseta</Name>
                  <Plural>Andorran pesetas</Plural>
                  <Active>false</Active>
                  <Digital>false</Digital>
               </Currency>

Comment: so, what do you need?

Comment: I want split that, like this 
 
<Currency> <Symbol>ADP</Symbol> <Name>Andorran peseta</Name> <Plural>Andorran pesetas</Plural> <Active>false</Active> <Digital>false</Digital> </Currency>

Comment: for example,
Symbol=ADP
 Countries=null,

Comment: How to parse this

Comment: I am still not getting that. Do you want to generate custom xml based on response? Can you post wwwXigniteComServices.Currencies class and childs referenced by that?

Comment: You need to check this class: Currencies. You dont need to parse the result it is already parsed and put into the a record with type of Currencies.

Comment: This is my apex class https://gist.github.com/anonymous/99390069d705ea27b6cc

Comment: So, you can see that inside of your response, there is a property, called **CurrencyList**, that has type **wwwXigniteComServices.ArrayOfCurrency**, inside which you can find array of **Currency_x[]**. In every cell of that array, there is a single instance of **Currency_x**, that have information that  you need. What and why do you need to parse - I dont know. WSDL do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `ListCurrencies()` are the corresponding return types:

```
public wwwXigniteComServices.Currencies ListCurrencies() { ... }

public class Currencies {
    public String Outcome;
    public String Message;
    public String Identity;
    public Double Delay;
    // ..._type_info    
    public wwwXigniteComServices.ArrayOfCurrency CurrencyList;
    // ..._type_info
}

public class ArrayOfCurrency {
    public wwwXigniteComServices.Currency_x[] Currency_x;
    // ..._type_info
}

public class Currency_x {
    public String Symbol;
    public String Name;
    public String Plural;
    public Boolean Active;
    public Boolean Digital;
    public String Message;
    public wwwXigniteComServices.ArrayOfCountry Countries;
    // ..._type_info
}
```

So you've got all the details you need there. Expanding it out from the end of your sample code:

```
wwwXigniteComServices.Currencies ListCurrenciesResult = testCls.ListCurrencies();


for(wwwXigniteComServices.Currency_x cur : ListCurrenciesResult.CurrencyList.Currency_c) {
    System.debug(cur.Symbol);
    System.debug(cur.Name);
    System.debug(cur.Plural);
    System.debug(cur.Active);
    System.debug(cur.Digital);
    System.debug(cur.Message);
}
```